# file.cpp from windows to linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I have a file.cpp which as an file.h included. This works on windows. Is there a easy way to change the code to be compiled on linux or do I have to rewrite all of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a real question, is it? How are we expected to answer this without knowing what the code does?

Comment: have you tried compiling it on linux already?

Comment: I was hoping that were a generic way to do it, we could apply. ok, well the code is an api from a plux biosensor device. It connects to the device throught blutooth and adquire some information from the sensor writting it to a txt.

Comment: @Timo yes, well the conio.h header does not exist on linux.

Comment: Folks, please vote to close it instead of posting pointless answers to pointless questions. Stop the reputation score hunt!

Comment: @SamuelNLP: There might easily be generic way to do it. But you didn't say _what_ is "it".

Comment: It seems clear to me - he is looking for tips on how to port from Windows to Linux.  There is a perfectly good answer below.

Comment: @SList Then he is supposed to re-phrase his question to reflect his intentions, instead of assuming folks use magic crystal balls. There is enough rubbish at SO already.

Comment: Well, as I said, it seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @mloskot as SList said, this may be a generic question so I wanted a generic answer. As the one given below. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Pointers towards Porting Code to different OS:

1. Check all the system headers included in the file. If there are OS specific headers, put them under OS specific macros and add different header files appropriate to Linux OS
2. Check all the system function calls and replace them.
3. Check if there are any compiler specific macros or code present and change it.
4. Check if the data types used are supported in all OS.